# Connecting via RDP changes performance options for all users

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I recently logged into a Windows server (virtual machine) via RDP, with the Windows Remote Desktop client, and due the fact that I am currently working from a small, under-powered laptop, all the visual effects were turned off, and the performance options were set to minimum values.

I expected that, but what I didn't expect was that the next time I connected to this server, I got the same configurations applied again, even though I was back on a machine that was more than powerful enough for higher settings.

What happened?  Did my remote desktop options get applied to the remote machine?  If I change the Remote Desktop settings back, will all users who login be affected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make preference changes, they *should* be just for your user - unless you're making GPO changes for a group.

Comment: Thank you for this Clarification. I will take a look why the settings of the other users where changed.

Comment: @JPVenson This is accurate. However, it can get very, *very*, **very** complicated. RDS settings can be configured for both the sever and the client side, as well as how they handle it when there are different settings between the two (whether the client settings get overridden or the server settings do).  Each component of this that I've described *can* be configured, either individually, or in groups, on either (or) both the client and server.  IF that's not complicated enough for you, some individual connection settings can also be configured with different client-override defaults as well.